# Debugger: no symbols have been loaded after renaming namespace

Tags: c#, silverlight, refactoring

I've got a Silverlight application with one Silverlight project and a host web project.

I renamed the namespace of the Silverlight application where the App.xaml is in. I did this via a refactoring tool. Afterwards the debugger just ignored the breakpoints. It's popping out the error shown in the title of this thread.

So I thought that maybe the refactoring tool fails, so I recovered the project with the old namespace in and renamed everything by hand (find in files). The app works, still, but I get the same error.

What the heck is this?

Comment: Restart visual studio, clean solution or remove all the files from the bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved this problem. My refactoring tool renamed everything fine. Even the name of the actual .xap file, which gets generated. The only thing which the refatoring tool did not fix is this line:

```
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/OldXapFileName.xap"/>
```

This was the reason, why the hosting project loaded the old xap file, everytime is started the application.

**@Andrei Schneider**: Thanks anyway. Your comment got me to deleting the ClientBin folder. So I've been asking myself why my application crashes, even though the new xap file got copied into the ClientBin folder.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the xap file name changed and you need to update the javascript to reflect the new name change. ;-)

Comment: That would be more impressive... if the asker had not stated that *was* his exact problem 15 minutes before you answered :)

Comment: Yep I got a hoot out of answering it after seeing his reply. :-)